# Update entry according to oldest entry in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have the following 2 tables (running on `SQL Server Compact Edition, Version 3.5.8080.0`):

```
tblInventory

|                     GUID_INVENTORYID |               DAT_DEADLINE |
|--------------------------------------|----------------------------|
| 13720A5F-F1F0-4420-AA9C-11CB955B86AA |         2014-05-01         |


tblInventoryDetails

|              GUID_INVENTORYDETAILSID |                     GUID_INVENTORYID |               DAT_INSERTED |
|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|----------------------------|
| EE222BCE-8182-4C70-A07C-7568838055A7 | 13720A5F-F1F0-4420-AA9C-11CB955B86AA |         2014-05-21         |
| 9BD8A3DC-31BE-418D-9F80-B88A50A58D31 | 13720A5F-F1F0-4420-AA9C-11CB955B86AA |         2014-05-10         |
```

There can be of course more then two entries in the `tblInventoryDetails`; All entries are linked to one entry in the `tblInventory`.

Now I want to update `dat_Deadline` according to the oldest `dat_Inserted` in `tblInventoryDetails` (which would be  `'2014-05-10'` in this case).
I know that I can get the oldest entry like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) dat_Inserted 
FROM tblInventoryDetails
WHERE GUID_INVENTORYID = @GUID_INVENTORYID
ORDER BY dat_Inserted
```

But how can I user that in my `UPDATE`-statement?
I also made a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84c6a/4) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE
  tblInventory
SET
  DAT_DEADLINE = 
  (
   SELECT MIN(DAT_INSERTED)
   FROM tblInventoryDetails 
   WHERE tblInventoryDetails.GUID_INVENTORYID = tblInventory.GUID_INVENTORYID
  )
WHERE
  tblInventory.GUID_INVENTORYID = '13720A5F-F1F0-4420-AA9C-11CB955B86AA'
```

another solution would be:

```
DECLARE @min_date datetime
SET @min_date = 
  (
   SELECT MIN(DAT_INSERTED)
   FROM tblInventoryDetails 
   WHERE tblInventoryDetails.GUID_INVENTORYID = '13720A5F-F1F0-4420-AA9C-11CB955B86AA'
  )

UPDATE
  tblInventory
SET
  DAT_DEADLINE = @min_date
WHERE
  tblInventory.GUID_INVENTORYID = '13720A5F-F1F0-4420-AA9C-11CB955B86AA'
```

Since it was pointed out that `nested selects` and `declare` do not work in SQL Server Compact Edition. A solution of two separate statements would more appropriate for this question.
First get the `min` date value and then `update` the proper table explicitly

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm getting an error `...Token in error = SELECT`. Could this come from limitations in `SQL-CE`?

Comment: Works ok in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84c6a/21) so maybe it's something else in the way you call the update script in your program

Comment: Yes, this kind of nested select does not Work, issue 2 statements, and store the intermediate value

Comment: @georstef Thanks for adding the second solution. Won't work either since one cannot use `DECLARE` in `SQLCE`.

Comment: @seph Then the 2 separate statements like ErikEJ suggested seems the proper solution. First get the min date value and then update explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL guru, but a subquery like this may help you.

```
UPDATE tblInventory
SET dat_deadline = (
  SELECT MIN(dat_Inserted)
  FROM tblInventoryDetails
  WHERE guid_InventoryID = '13720A5F-F1F0-4420-AA9C-11CB955B86AA'
);
```

Comment: This will update all the entries in `tblInventory` with the date from one particular `tblInventoryDetails` which will be wrong

Comment: Yep, need to add WHERE clause to reference correct inventory ID.